# Calculate cooldown between new platform spawning. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, logic

I'm making endless runner. I made platform spawning script where i calculate the cooldown between spawning each new platform depends on speed and platform length. I'm using this formula:

```
spawnCooldown = platformLenght * (1 / platfowmMovingSpeed);
```

this finds how far it moves in 1 second. BUT! It dosen't work as i want and i dont know why.

> For example: PlatfromLenght = 4; platformMovingSpeed = 20;
> spawnCooldown = 4 * (1/20); spawnCooldown = 0.2sec.

For this it works fine but when speed is 17 or 23 or another value that Not 10 or 20, i get empty space between platforms. i would be appreciated for any ideas about that.

Comment: I made a question and got "-1" vote. Why? For what? Is this site work like this? Rly?
Nice help, thx guys!

Comment: You get empty spaces because you use Update method and change the position of the player using translate. Try converting every movement into Unity physics and move update code into fixedupdate.

Comment: I move platforms, not player. Actually maybe my whole my concept how it should be is wrong but i have what i have...
I solved my problem, now instead of changing speed of each platform i changing timescale. This is not good solution but in this case it works good.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, now instead of changing speed of each platform i changing timescale. This is not good solution but in this case it works good.